# Taylor theorem equation

Tags: optimization

I have one question about Taylor theorem.

Originally, Taylor theorem is represented as

$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \ldots$$

But my book says

Suppose that $$f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$$ is continuously differentiable and that $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$
Then we have that
$$f(x + p) = f(x) + ∇f(x+tp)^Tp$$

But I don't understand how to derive this equation from Taylor theorem.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's not $\nabla f(x)^T$?

Comment: Yes... I write down this equation from book, numerical optimization.

Comment: @mangken No, it must be as user7530 said, otherwise it makes no sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This equality follows from the mean value theorem applied to the function $ g (s) = f (x + sp) , 0 \leq s \leq 1$.

By the mean value theorem, there exists $ t \in (0,1)$ such that $ g (1) -g (0) = g'(t) = \nabla f (x + tp)^T p$.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!. reallyy helpful in my study.. !!

Answer (score 5):

The formula you have is incorrect (what is $t$ anyway?); it should be $\nabla f(x)^T$ at which point it is simply Taylor's theorem for functions of several variables.

A derivation of the multivariate Taylor's theorem should be covered in *any* introductory textbook on multivariable calculus; I'm very surprised that yours does not. There are plenty of course notes available online that also explain it, for instance [here](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~bryan/lottamath/mtaylor.pdf).

EDIT: Looking at Nocedal and Wright it seems that what you are actually after is the multivariate mean value theorem: for $f$ differentiable in a sufficiently large neighborhood of $x$, there exists a $t \in [0,1]$ with
$$f(x+p) = f(x) + \nabla f(x+tp)^Tp.$$
You can see this directly from the single variable mean value theorem, see e.g. the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables).

Comment: Thank you for your answering. but, book says this contents.  i am confusing now..

Comment: @mangken What book is that and where in it is that formula?

Comment: Numerical Optimization, Jorge Nocedal Stephen J. Wright, 14 page...  you can see this formula.

Comment: Maybe the book is presenting a mean value theorem.  In other words, a zeroth order Taylor expansion with the remainder term included.

Comment: really thank you for all answer.t is (0,1) value.